# How to append child page in Phundament 3?

Tags: php, phundament

I'm just get started with phundament  following the instructions on the home page.

> **Create Child Page** 
>   Go to your index page. Click Append Child Page in the top menu. Select Main Layout and save.

I expected to find the  parent id page  in the **Tree Parent** combo box, but there is *undefined*. I see in URL  **[tree_parent_id]=2**  which is not assigned to  **Tree Parent**.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to http://demo.phundament.com/3.0-dev/
2. Login as admin /admin
3. Go to http://demo.phundament.com/3.0-dev/index.php?r=p3pages/default/index&lang=en
4. Create a page
5. Try to create child page with the green button with plus sign on the right side with tool-tip "Append Child Page"

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue, I think I'll have to update the demo page.

Comment: @schmunk Thank you for the Phundament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append child page in phundament with **p3pages ver. 0.17.3**   the **new page** and the **parent page** should be in same "Access Domain" / language.

#### Steps to reproduce:

Steps 1 to 3 are same as above.

4.Create a page and **set "Access Domain" / language**

5.Try to create child page with the green button with plus sign on the right side with tool-tip "Append Child Page"

Now you should see the parent name page in the "Tree Parent" combo box.

---

You can also upgrade to **p3pages ver. 0.17.4** via [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) when a parent page may be in the same language or "All languages".

In the root of your phundament installation just type

<kbd>composer require "phundament/p3pages"</kbd>

Then composer will asks for version

> Please provide a version constraint for the phundament/p3pages
> requirement:

Type

<kbd>0.17.4</kbd>

and you should see something like the bellow

> ./composer.json has been updated
>
> Phundament
>
> Upgrading packages...
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
> dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> - Removing phundament/p3pages (0.17.3)
> - Installing phundament/p3pages (0.17.4)
>   Downloading: 100%
>
> Writing lock file Generating autoload files composer.callback:
> post-update